# Borderbrush coloranimation fade in and out

Tags: wpf, animation, border, coloranimation

i have a border , and i change it's borderbrush in the run time.
now i need this border to be glowing all the time, whatever the color was.

i tried this but i have problems. any one can help?

```
<Border   Name="ActiveBorder"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="auto"  BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="2" >
            <Border.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Duration="00:00:01" To="Transparent"></ColorAnimation>       
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
        </Border.Style>
```

Comment: this is gong to make it "pulsate" or "blink" is this what you want?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to specify:

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush.Color"
```

and either specify:

```
BorderBrush="any-non-transparent-color"
```

or in the animation:

```
From="any-non-transparent-color"
```

Comment: That worked, Great. thank you. But why can't i use the "Transparent". It will be more powerfull !!!

Comment: because if you use Transparent, you will have an animation starting from transparent and moving to tyransparent, so nothing happens.

Comment: As i'm learning more about animation, i can't bind the color property of the animation. i'm having an exception at run time !! any ideas?

Comment: This is the new question. Thanks.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240480/binding-color-value-for-coloranimation

Comment: Setting the StoryBoard.TargetPropertly="BorderBrush.Color" complains that BorderBrush has no Color property. Do you know is that solves the problem?